# Place iAd on bottom of every app's screen and change screen height

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

I want to add iAd in my app in a way that it will be shown on every screen, and the content area should be resized to provide area for banner.

So, for example, without banner my screen height is 568, and the content takes all of those 568 points.

However, with ads my content will take 518 points, and last 50 points are taken by banner.

How can I achieve that? I've tried changing root view frame, and adding iAd banner as subview of root view with appropriate frame, but it leads to my iAd banner being unclickable as it ends up outside of it's superview.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think that you'd have to do it all on your own, having every subview of `self.view` of `UIViewController` to have to know about the bottom 50 points by adding a UIView at the bottom of every VC manually.

Gladly, it can be done in about a couple of hours in the storyboard. There might be a better way though, but I doubt it.